# What is an elegant way of toggling the visibility of UI sections?

Tags: android, kotlin

I build Android apps using the MVP pattern and I'm often breaking up my UI into various sections like this:

```
<ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/recyclerSection"
<ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/errorSection"
<ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/emptySection"
```

Then in my presenter I'll call

```
view.showError()
```

and my view ends up with functions that look like this:

```
override fun showError(){
  recyclerSection.visibility = View.GONE
  errorSection.visibility = View.VISIBLE
  emptySection.visibility = View.GONE
}

override fun showList(){
  recyclerSection.visibility = View.VISIBLE
  errorSection.visibility = View.GONE
  emptySection.visibility = View.GONE
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to code this to achieve this toggling of view sections?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with elegant? Here's an fade extension which is pretty nice

```
fun View.fadeToVisible(time: Long) {
    alpha = 0f
    animate()
        .alpha(1f)
        .setDuration(time)
        .withStartAction {
            visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
    .start()
}

fun View.fadeToGone(time: Long) {
    alpha = 1f
    animate()
        .alpha(0f)
        .setDuration(time)
        .withEndAction {
            visibility = View.GONE
        }
    .start()
}
```

And then you use it like this (with 200 ms time):

```
override fun showError(){
    recyclerSection.fadeToGone(200)
    errorSection.fadeToVisible(200)
    emptySection.fadeToGone(200)
}

override fun showList(){
    recyclerSection.fadeToVisible(200)
    errorSection.fadeToGone(200)
    emptySection.fadeToGone(200)
}
```

However it's a matter of taste :)

Comment: Sorry, I meant elegant coding wise, not visually...but I like your thinking!